# Can i install VSTS on my own server firm?

Tags: azure-devops

I know Azure Websites has released a version of its cloud manager to install it on its own server firm.

Likewise, I would like to install VSTS on my own server firm.

Is there also a setup version available for Visual Studio Team Services ?

Comment: As Daniel said that VSTS is cloud-hosted, you can use it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean Team foundation server, based on the [requirements of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements), you can install TFS on your server, need to meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my "names" confusion. Moreover it's possible to install TFS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/get-started), your answer isn't totally accurate

Comment: Yes, you can install TFS, because it is on-premise, if portable version means can install on local server, you're right.

Comment: Yes sorry my question isn't clear, i update a little my question.

Comment: @GGO Update the answer too. You can accept Daniel or my reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Team Foundation Server is the on-prem version of Visual Studio Team Services.

Or, more accurately, VSTS is the cloud-hosted version of TFS.

Comment: I can't use it directly in cloud, i have to host it on my own server firm

Comment: Understood, @GGO.  Despite the name change, yes, TFS _is_ the portable version of Visual Studio Team Services, and you install it within your data center.

Comment: @CGO Install Team Foundation Server. It's the name of the on-premise version of Visual Studio Team Services.